# hdbscan vs dbscan in how they cluster the data of varying shapes and density

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

Can you explain this passage please:

"A key feature of HDBScan is that it clusters data of varying density, this is in comparison to DBScan, which tend to cluster data of varying shapes only."

Comment: Besides adding more details, can you also fix your title?

Comment: I fixed the title, but I don't know what to add as details, the question is clear I think.

Comment: You can add the source of the passage, provide wiki references for these algorithms.